# ins1.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, console

I am recently having a problem with javascript code. The script changes its `<ins data-ad-slot="4092520690">` paramater to `<ins data-ad-slot-"9020596432">` after 3 clicks. But there is a slight console error. 
It says that 'ins1.addEventListener is not a function'.

The error: [image: error]

The javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('ins')){
            const ins1 = document.getElementsByTagName('4092520690');
            var newIns = sessionStorage.getItem('ins');
            var newParam = sessionStorage.getItem('param')
            ins1.param = newParam;
            ins1.innerText = newIns;
        }
    });

    function replaceAfter3Clicks(elem, newElem) {
        let count = 0;
        ins1.addEventListener('click', () => {
            count ++;
            if (count === 3) {
                sessionStorage.clear(); // Clear all sessionStorage
                sessionStorage.setItem('ins', "ins 2"); // First param is the name and the second is the value
                sessionStorage.setItem('data-ad-slot', "4092520690");// First param is the name and the second is the value
                elem.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, elem);
            }
         });
    }

    const ins1 = document.getElementsByTagName('4092520690');

    // pre-made second div for future replacement
    const ins2 = document.createElement('ins');
    ins2.param = '9020596432';
    ins2.innerText = 'ins 2';
    replaceAfter3Clicks(ins1, ins2);
```

Could somebody maybe enlighten me what the problem is with line

`ins1.addEventListener('click', () => {`
and
`replaceAfter3Clicks(ins1, ins2);` is.

Answer (score 1):

You've got:

```
const ins1 = document.getElementsByTagName('4092520690');
```

[`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a node list. [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) only applies to nodes, not entire node lists. **Also (FYI) `.getElementsByTagName()` does just that and `4092520690` is not a valid tag name so you should probably rethink your HTML a bit.**

With "vanilla" JavaScript, you'll have to iterate over the nodes in `ins1` an execute `.addEventListener()` on each of them or you can set up the listener on an ancestor of those nodes and check the `event.target` to see if the node that actually triggered the event is one that you care about and, if so, act accordingly.

But, since you are using JQuery anyway, you could change your lines to:

```
const ins1 = $("some valid selector");
ins1.on('click', () => { ... });
```

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName() ` returns a HTMLCollection !

Comment: @kmgt An HTMLCollection is a type of [Node List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `ins1` is not an element, but an array-like object of elements. And arrays (nor array-like objects) can't have event listeners added to them.

What you need to do is look through `ins1` and add an event listener to each element within it; something like:

```
function replaceAfter3Clicks(elem, newElem) {
    let count = 0;
    let callback = function() {
        count ++;

        if (count === 3) {
            sessionStorage.clear(); // Clear all sessionStorage
            sessionStorage.setItem('ins', "ins 2"); // First param is the name and the second is the value
            sessionStorage.setItem('data-ad-slot', "4092520690");// First param is the name and the second is the value
            elem.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, elem);
        }
    };

    Array.from(ins1).forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', callback);
    }
});
```